# TFS 2010, Check-In Dialog, display date of CheckOut?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

Does anyone know, if there is a possibility, to show the date of the check-out in the check-in dialog?

This would have the advantage for me, if i want to check-in all files with a known date of the checkout, e.g. all files i checked out today, than i could just sort them instead of search them and compare every single file.

It is not unusual that my list of checked out files becomes a bit longer until i am able to check them in again.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: I don't believe TFS tracks this. If it does I don't think it is easily accessible. If you have files checked out that you aren't planning on working on for a while you should consider using a shelveset. Also, VS 2012 and higher take care of this for you as you can suspend work.

Comment: This sounds like a very bad practice. Having files checked out for multiple days is asking for trouble...

Comment: I know, but its not possible to end some kind of tasks in less than one day... Sometimes you also need to wait for work to be finished by your colleges. And than something is more important than the current work and than you come into this situation. Therefor, the thing i asked for, would be nice to have.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe this is possible within VS.  However, if you install [TFS Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f017b10c-02b4-4d6d-9845-58a06545627f), you should be able to perform a check-in from Windows Explorer; then (and this is by no means an exact science) you could sort by Date Created.  I believe this should give you what you want.

A possibly better way to do this would be to make use of multiple workspaces.  If you're working on things that can be independently checked in, then separating them using workspaces seems to make more sense; this also prevents the possibility of you booking in some changes that rely on other changes that you may have done on a different day.

Comment: That is a good hint. I didn't knew of different workspaces before your answer. I will investigate that if it could be a possible solution for my scenarios. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I know you are on TFS2010 and possibly VS2010 but in VS 2012/Team Explorer Everywhere you have the option of excluding and Including files during check-in. YOu should probably check it out.

[image]

Check this link below:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj155786.aspx